# Assign same key to values gotten from dynamic Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array received from backend: `["Drake","Ola","d"]`, now I need to assign all these values the same key which is `id` so it looks something like this:

```
[{id: "Drake"}, {id: "Ola"}, {id: "d"}]
```

I need a function to do this as the data is gotten after the page has loaded and I have tried many techniques including `for loops`. 
I can also use JQuery if necessary, whats the solution please?

Comment: In an `object` you can't have multiple keys with same name.

Comment: Properties Keys in object must be unique

Comment: An object can't have multiple properties by the same name, are you sure this is the correct data-structure you are looking for?

Comment: and which one would you like to get with `obj.id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Maybe you actually  want something alone the lines of `[{id:"Drake"}, {id:"Dola"}]` etc? So it remains an array you can iterate. What's your use case?

Comment: Consider using array `[{id: "Drake"}, {id: "Ola"},{ id: "d"}]` in your case as properies are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and generate single objects with the wanted content.

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var data = ["Drake","Ola","d"],
    result = data.map(function (a) { return { id: a }; });

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var data = ["Drake","Ola","d"],
    result = data.map(a => ({ id: a }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: please dv, care to comment?

Comment: I guess it was because your original answer was a guess to a bad question. Now OP seems to of clarified this makes more sense. BTW, I didn't downvote

Comment: @Liam, that's funny, because ["Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ha, though you should [never answer an off topic question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) and [questions should be answerable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) :)

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should do the trick. Just create an object for each value with the `id` property being that value.

```js
var array = ["Drake","Ola","d"];

var newArray = array.map(function(value){
  return {id: value}
})
console.log(newArray);
```